# Can I write a code like this? Is it a bad writing?

Tags: python, function

Basically, i want to change the first & last letter in a string with eachother:
'Sonic' to 'Conis'
I saw a solution like this:

```
def first_last(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
       return string
mid = string[1:len(string)-1]
return string[len(string)-1] + mid + string[0]
```

but i wrote it a bit different because mine is simpler for me:

```
def first_last(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
       return string
    mid = string[1:-1]
    return string[-1] + mid + string[0]
```

Does my code pose a problem?

Comment: Do you have *any* evidence of a problem?

Comment: That's no problem. In fact it's better. I would just drop `mid` and write `return string[-1] + string[1:-1] + string[0]`. And of course both solutions miss to change uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Does it work? Can you understand it yourself? If YES to both, then it's not clear what's the problem.

Comment: You never do anything with capitalization - also see @Matthias solution - also IndentationError in the 1st solution

Comment: You can write even shorter: `return string[-1] + string[1:-1] + string[0]` and remove `mid = string[1:-1]`

Comment: google `python switch last and first letter of word site:stackoverflow.com` for plenty similar questions with solutions.

Comment: Thank you everyone to have responded to my question, helped me a lot, to understand a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Most coders would not consider this "bad". The only reason to assign the string slice `string[1:-1]` to the variable `mid` would be to increase readability. And readability counts!

This variable assigment would probably be more useful if you had a longer function that used the mid variable multiple times. At that point, you might want to consider assigning `string[0]` and `string[-1]` to their own variables as well.

Comment: Thanks man, I understood clearly now.